# WinServer 2019 Standard Https Issue

Tags: windows, google-chrome, https, server, hsts

Recently installed Windows Server 2019 Standard (legit and activated) and migrated my mail server over to this server. I noticed after I was done that I cannot browse the web if the website uses https. Below I attached pictures and I have tried to research and really haven't found much. Google Chrome will not let me even try to visit any https websites. While at the same time IE will let me continue on but websites do not load properly. Windows update is 100% up to date.

Google Chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tru6g.jpg

Internet Explorer
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTgCW.jpg

Comment: I would suggest this is far more suited to https://superuser.com/

Comment: I will copy this post over there. Thank you